# How many growth spurts does a child usually go through?

Tags: growth

How many growth spurts does a child usually go through, and are there common age ranges when they go through their growth spurts? At what age do children usually stop growing?

Comment: It seems like I'm buying new shoes for my son every 4 months!  He just turned 3 and he's in a toddler's 10 already.  If he grows into his feet he's going to beggar me!

Answer (score 3):

It truly depends on the age of the child in question.

- Newborns will go through growth spurts every few weeks.
- From toddlerhood through early adolescence growth spurts occur every few months (every child is different, but it can range from 3 to 9 months in frequency).
- The most noticeable growth occurs at puberty
- Growth spurts will continue to occur in most young adults through their early twenties, however they will be relatively infrequent and irregular.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when they'll stop, end of puberty maybe, but I've been told (and it seems to hold up) that they'll hit a growth spurt about every 6-9 months.

Answer (score 0):

As per @cabbey's answer it seems to be a bit over six months for the first few years at least. My 10 year old seems to have slowed a bit: maybe 10 month between his last couple.